# How to get average watch time for a youtube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

According to Youtube Analytics documentation, you can only get watch time for videos uploaded to your own channel, and you can't get it for playlisted videos (except in the context of a playlist, which is useless to me). The documentation also states that if you want to access watch time information, you need a permission from the owner of the channel.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/#Report_Contents

Is it possible to get Average Watch Time for any youtube video using Youtube data API or Analytics API, or using any other source and how?

Answer (score 1):

You may check [`averageViewDuration`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#Watch_Time_Metrics) which is the average length, in seconds, of video playbacks. In a playlist report, the metric indicates the average length, in seconds, of video playbacks that occurred in the context of a playlist.

[Example:](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#Channel_Reports)

**Total view counts, estimated watch time, and more for a channel**

This query retrieves aggregated metrics for the channel's content. The report returns a single row of data that contains totals for each requested metric during the specified date range.

```
metrics=views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,averageViewDuration
```

Hope this helps!